# Lazy match front part in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
Steve Jobs steve.jobs@example.com somethingElse
```

I hope to match `steve.jobs@example.com somethingElse` (a space in front)

This is my regular expression (JavaScript)

```
\s.+?@.+
```

But now it matches `Jobs steve.jobs@example.com somethingElse` (a space in front)

I know I can use `?` to lazy match the following part, but how to lazy match front part?

Comment: `\s\S+@.+`? There is no rightmost lazy matching, you'll either have to use a negated character class or a tempered greedy token approach.

Comment: `\s(.+?@.+)` extract first captured group.

Comment: Use `(\S+@\S+)\s*(\S+)` and extract first & second captured groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.` can be any character, including the whitespaces.

Normally e-mails don't contain whitespaces. 
(although it's actually allowed between 2 `"`)

So you could change the regex so that it looks for non-whitespaces `\S` before and after the `@`.
It can be greedy.

A whitespace followed by 1 or more non-whitespaces and a `@` and 1 or more non-whitespaces. Then by whitespace(s) and something else:

```
\s(\S+@\S+)(?:\s+(\S+))?
```

Comment: I tried Tushar and gurvinder372's too, and they both work. But I feel this one with `\S` help is a very smart solution!

Comment: Well, something like `\S+@\S+` is short alright. But it would also capture a string with more than 1 `@`. Something like `[^\s@]+[@][^\s@]+[.]\w+` would be slightly more accurate to capture an e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `trim`, `split` and `pop`

```
var output = "Steve Jobs steve.jobs@example.com ".trim().split(" ").pop();
```

**Regex solution**

You can use `trim` and `match`

```
var output = "Steve Jobs steve.jobs@example.com ".trim().match( /[\w.]+@[\w.]+/g )
```

*Regex* - `/[\w.]+@[\w.]+$/gi`

**Edit**

```
var output = "Steve Jobs steve.jobs@example.com somethingelse ".trim().match( /[\w.]+@[\w.]+/g )
```

**Demo**

```js
var  regex = /[\w.]+@[\w.]+/g;

var input1 = "Steve Jobs steve.jobs@example.com ";
var input2 = "Steve Jobs steve.jobs@example.com somethingelse ";

var fn = (str) => str.trim().match(regex);

console.log( fn(input1) );
console.log( fn(input2) );
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my questions a little bit by adding `somethingElse`, to reveal the more complex real problem. (Sorry, I think I simplified too much at first)

Comment: @HongboMiao Please try the regex solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

The allowed characters in an email are;

```
*0-9* | *a-z* | *. - _*
```

And it must have a @ symbol too.

So our regex must start with allowed characters,

```
[a-zA-z0-9-_.]
```

It must continue with @ symbol;

```
[a-zA-z0-9-_.]+@
```

Then it can end with .com or anything which includes dot

```
[a-zA-z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-z0-9.]+
```